# Primefaces Datatable reset selection state after click outside of Browser

Tags: primefaces, datatable, selection

After selected a row in the datatable and when i click outside of the browser or change the tab of browser the selected row reseted to the first row : you can see this if you navigate to http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml and go to secend example "Single with Row Click" and select the third row than click outside of Browser and return you will see that the row was reseted. thank's.

Comment: I don't see that issue !

Comment: Several people in the PrimeFaces forum and issuelist state they **cannot** reproduce with the PrimeFaces showcase. And now you are trying here. Compliments for your perseverance, But I strongly suggest to investigate your browsers etc...